# getting error on creation Oracle JSON Search Index

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle12.1

My Oracle version: 12c 12.1.0.2.0

i want to create a search index for json field. this is the code i run.

```
CREATE INDEX po_search_idx ON j_purchaseorder (po_document)
  INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT
  PARAMETERS ('section group CTXSYS.JSON_SECTION_GROUP SYNC (ON COMMIT)');
```

result

```
[Error] Execution (1: 1): ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-12203: section group CTXSYS.JSON_SECTION_GROUP does not exist
ORA-06512: a "CTXSYS.DRUE", line 160
ORA-06512: a "CTXSYS.TEXTINDEXMETHODS", line 366
```

I think it is necessary to create a section group. how can i do this?
I did a search but I don't understand how to create this specific group.

Comment: Was your database upgraded from 11g to 12c? [This might be a known issue.](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/1957005_1.html) That support note shows how to create the missing section group, but you'll need an account (and support contract) to see the details.

Comment: no upgraded from 11g.

Comment: Also 12.1 is not a recommended release, esp for JSON feature support - you should upgrade to 19c at your earliest opportunity.

Comment: @nickb84 - the fix is probably the same anyway.